# I cannot get shadow to work on my search bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-elements

I am failing to get a shadow around my search bar. I am using react native elements search bar that can be found here [here](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/searchbar/). I am implementing it in the way the code below shows. I am assuming my containerStyle is what you guys need to be looking at.

Thank you for any insight at all. I appreciate it more than you know.

```
 <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', }}>
          <SearchBar
            placeholder="Search..."
            onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
            value={search}
            round="true"
            containerStyle={styles.searchBarContainer}
            inputContainerStyle={{
              height: scale(45),
              width: scale(200),
              backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
              borderRadius: 10
              
            }}
            searchIcon={() => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="glass-mug-variant"
                size={25}
                color="#87909A"
              />
            )}
            clearIcon="null"
          />
          </View>

const styles = ScaledSheet.create({
    searchBarContainer: {
      textShadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 1 },
      textShadowRadius: 2,
      textShadowColor: 'black',
      backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf',
      borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
      borderTopColor: 'transparent',
      paddingRight: scale(20),
      paddingLeft: scale(20),
             
    },
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Replace this line **backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'**
to this **backgroundColor: '#e0dbdb'** OR use color picker to find the Hex Code of the color of your choice.